# How to find a word in a string phrase in a list?

Tags: python

When I do this code it returns false, I wanted it to return True because the "hello" is into "hello word".

```
a = ["hello world", 22]
print("hello" in a)
```

It' return false, not True.

If i do (not in a list):

```
a = "hello world"
print("hello" in a)
```

It's return True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do what you need:

```
any(["hello" in str(x) for x in a])
```

Comment: This would be (in this case _very_ slightly) more efficient using a generator expression rather than a list comprehension.  `any("hello" in str(x) for x in a)`

Comment: worked, returned True, but is the only way to do that? need to use any, for and make this syntax? is there more simple way?

Comment: Apart from the improvement proposed by @Chris here (that improves speed by around 15%, according to my tests") you could use `any(map(lambda x: "hello" in str(x), a))`, which appears to be faster as well.

Comment: nice! how do i ignore uppercase? Hello not hello

Comment: @Chead do `str(x).lower()`